# Уменьшение изображения с svg маской

Tags: css, svg, img, clip-path

```css
img{width:320px;clip-path:path('M315.001 6.24132e-06H5.00202C2.2578 6.24132e-06 0.0102067 2.24165 0.00226772 4.9853C0.00226772 4.99012 0.00226772 4.99579 0.00226772 4.99976L0 78.4571C42.071 106.567 183.196 189.999 242.162 189.999C275.504 189.999 309.914 113.388 319.995 78.4571L320 4.99976L320 4.9235C319.959 2.2082 317.724 0 315.001 0L315.001 6.24132e-06Z')}
```

```html
  <img src="https://scx1.b-cdn.net/csz/news/800a/2018/rooster.jpg" alt="">
```

Есть изображение с svg маской, подскажите пожалуйста как сделать чтобы маска с изображением сохраняла свои пропорции при именьшении. Т.е. если сделать img шириной 200px, то она просто обрезается

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> как сделать чтобы маска с изображением сохраняла свои пропорции при
> именьшении. Т.е. если сделать img шириной 200px, то она просто
> обрезается

так происходит, потому что вы взяли в качестве CSS clip-path `svg path(M315..)` , который имеет фиксированные размеры `width="320px"` `height="190px"`

Поэтому, если задать `img` размеры равные размерам clip-path `320px` то всё будет отображаться нормально.

- Если увеличить размеры img, то картинка увеличится, но будет
  обрезаться по размерам clip-path - 320px
- Если уменьшить размеры img, например до 220px, то вы не увидите часть
  clip-path, так как он больше картинки на 100px.

Чтобы сделать clip-path адаптивным необходимо добавить `viewBox`

Чтобы узнать атрибуты viewBox используем метод JS `getBBox()`

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  style="border:1px solid red">
<path id="path" fill="none" stroke="black" d="M315.001 6.24132e-06H5.00202C2.2578 6.24132e-06 0.0102067 2.24165 0.00226772 4.9853C0.00226772 4.99012 0.00226772 4.99579 0.00226772 4.99976L0 78.4571C42.071 106.567 183.196 189.999 242.162 189.999C275.504 189.999 309.914 113.388 319.995 78.4571L320 4.99976L320 4.9235C319.959 2.2082 317.724 0 315.001 0L315.001 6.24132e-06Z" />
</svg>
<script> 
let bb = path.getBBox();
console.log(bb);
</script>
```

Добавляем `viewBox="0 0 320 190"` и `width="320"` чтобы получить изображение с clip-path, как в вашем примере

```css
image{
clip-path: url(#cp);
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="320" viewBox="0 0 320 190"> 
<defs> 
<clipPath id="cp">
 <path id="path" fill="none" stroke="black" d="M315.001 6.24132e-06H5.00202C2.2578 6.24132e-06 0.0102067 2.24165 0.00226772 4.9853C0.00226772 4.99012 0.00226772 4.99579 0.00226772 4.99976L0 78.4571C42.071 106.567 183.196 189.999 242.162 189.999C275.504 189.999 309.914 113.388 319.995 78.4571L320 4.99976L320 4.9235C319.959 2.2082 317.724 0 315.001 0L315.001 6.24132e-06Z" />
 </clipPath>
 </defs> 
 <image href="https://scx1.b-cdn.net/csz/news/800a/2018/rooster.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" />
</svg>
```

Теперь уменьшаем ширину до `width="220px"`

```css
image{
clip-path: url(#cp);
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="220" viewBox="0 0 320 190"> 
<defs> 
<clipPath id="cp">
 <path id="path" fill="none" stroke="black" d="M315.001 6.24132e-06H5.00202C2.2578 6.24132e-06 0.0102067 2.24165 0.00226772 4.9853C0.00226772 4.99012 0.00226772 4.99579 0.00226772 4.99976L0 78.4571C42.071 106.567 183.196 189.999 242.162 189.999C275.504 189.999 309.914 113.388 319.995 78.4571L320 4.99976L320 4.9235C319.959 2.2082 317.724 0 315.001 0L315.001 6.24132e-06Z" />
 </clipPath>
 </defs> 
 <image href="https://scx1.b-cdn.net/csz/news/800a/2018/rooster.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" />
</svg>
```

**Видим, что clip-path уменьшился с соблюдением пропорций**

Но размеры останутся постоянными при изменении размеров окна браузера.

Чтобы сделать его адаптивным, зададим ширину и высоту SVG в процентах

```
width="25%" height="25%"
```

```css
image{
clip-path: url(#cp);
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="25%" height="25%" viewBox="0 0 320 190"> 
<defs> 
<clipPath id="cp">
 <path id="path" fill="none" stroke="black" d="M315.001 6.24132e-06H5.00202C2.2578 6.24132e-06 0.0102067 2.24165 0.00226772 4.9853C0.00226772 4.99012 0.00226772 4.99579 0.00226772 4.99976L0 78.4571C42.071 106.567 183.196 189.999 242.162 189.999C275.504 189.999 309.914 113.388 319.995 78.4571L320 4.99976L320 4.9235C319.959 2.2082 317.724 0 315.001 0L315.001 6.24132e-06Z" />
 </clipPath>
 </defs> 
 <image href="https://scx1.b-cdn.net/csz/news/800a/2018/rooster.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо!

Comment: @RickHangover Пожалуйста. Задавайте ещё вопросы.